# How to commit server and client folders separately?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, commit, react-fullstack

Please help me to know, how to commit server and client folder.
I started a new project. And i want to write back-end node-js, and front-end react-js.
I created 2 folders "client" for react, and "server" for node. I have two terminals for node and for react.
When i want to commit, git says that i have ../client folder. But i want to commit it separately.
If i'll commit it together i have to go to root folder and create third .env file, because node_modules not ignored in clients folder.

I need your help, maybe this question is easy, but for me this issue very heavy. I can't understand how can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, from what i can understand you have 3 simple options,

**Option 1: A "True" Monorepo with npm workspaces**

You will need `npm@7` or later.

With this option you take advantage of [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) to manage dependencies for both the client and the server.

The folder structure would look something like this

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ .git/
├─ client/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ index.js/
├─ server/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ index.js
├─ package.json
```

`.git/` is the where git actually stores it's data, so it's parent folder is the repo, in this case `my-app/`

To use [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) you would setup a `package.json` in the root of `my-app/` like so

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "workspaces": [
    "server",
    "client"
  ]
}
```

`npm init -w ./server -w ./client` could help,

To install dependencies you can do `npm i @some-org/some-package -w client`, the `-w` flag is also respected for `uninstall` and `ci`.

Calling `npm install` will install dependencies for all workspaces.

You then use git as usual, and both client and server are in the same repo, just make sure to add a `.gitignore` in `my-app/` and to track all `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.

**Option 2: Two co-located projects in a "Monorepo"**

This option is simple, but can lead to complexity with things like dependencies, so is often best avoided except for small projects without inter-project dependencies.

With a folder structure like so

```
my-app/
├─ .git/
├─ client/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ node_modules/
├─ server/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ node_modules/
```

You will need to make sure you're in the right folder when installing dependencies.

Here both projects are separate, but are part of the same repo.

**Option 3: Two git repos**

I don't recommend this option, but this will work too.

```
my-app/
├─ client/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ node_modules/
│  ├─ .git/
├─ server/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ node_modules/
│  ├─ .git/
```

just make sure `my-app/` doesn't have a `.git/` folder in it's root.

`ls -a` will print hidden files/folders.

Comment: Your welcome, out of curiosity what option did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can go about this in one of two ways.

By adding .../client folder to your .gitignor file.
Separate it to different branches i.e 'frontend' and 'backend'

Comment: hmm, separate branches it's interesting idea. I will try it. But when i wrote ../client to gitignore nothing change. I can't ignore it. 
i will look for reason, why i can't ignore this folder, and i will try to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Or you can create separate repositories for frontend and backend (as done by companies having separate teams for frontend and backend). In this case, you'll have to delete your existing `.git` folder and setup git repository inside both folders in the same fashion.